# Trying to Create a Partition for Storage

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to create a second partition on my HP M7 running Ubuntu with a 1TB hard drive. I want at the very least a 400 GB second partition for my family photos and what not.

When I use GParted, this is the error I come up with...

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B54V_bH3_i02ZE9nWDI4QlVWczg&usp=sharing

At picture #4, I cannot change any values! Has this happened to anyone?

Comment: I noticed that your partition is encrypted. I'd be VERY CAREFUL about resizing it. Please refer to this [official help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to resize the extended partition (`/dev/sda2`), which serves as a container for logical partitions. The partition you should be trying to resize is the logical partition (`/dev/sda5`). You could then either resize the extended partition and create a new primary partition or (better in most cases) create a new logical partition within the extended partition without resizing it. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/PartitioningBasics) or do a Web search to learn more about the differences between partition types. Note that these distinctions apply only to the older [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partition table; the newer [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) doesn't draw these distinctions or have a 4-primary-partition limit. (I mention this mainly for completeness; you have an MBR disk and so are tied to MBR's rules.)

In addition, heed hmayag's comment about the fact that you're using an encrypted partition. You'll need to jump through some extra hoops to resize it safely.